# Запятая перед или

Tags: запятые, или

Я совсем запуталась. Объясните мне доступно. Сегодня спорила с начальником по поводу запятой в этом выражении:

> Флейта-пикколо(,) или малая флейта.

Я утверждала, что перед или нужна запятая, так как союз или имеет значение то есть и слово малая флейта является вторым названием флейты-пикколо. Мне говорят, что эти слова являются однородными. А как же тогда в предложении: Не обитает на территории России бегемот, или гиппопотам. Или: В южных частях Уссурийского края встречается пятнистый олень, или аксис.
Почему тогда в предложении: Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется окончанием или флексией - мне утверждают, что перед или запятая не нужна. Я же рассуждаю, что флексия -это второе название окончания, и запятая перед или нужна.
Пожалуйста, жду помощи и объяснения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "Сегодня спорила с начальником по поводу запятой в этом выражении:Флейта-пикколо или малая флейта. Я утверждала, что перед или нужна запятая..."===

Может, правы Вы, может -- начальник... А каков контекст у выражения?

Comment: В тексте речь шла о концерте. Автор перечислял,кто на чем играл, флейта-пикколо или малая флейта просто были заключены в скобки

Comment: Тогда запятая нужна. Ведь этот "кто-то" не на двух же инструментах играл...

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

*Флейта-пикколо, или малая флейта* - верно, в значении "то есть".

```
Почему тогда в предложении: Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется окончанием или флексией - мне утверждают, что перед ИЛИ запятая не нужна. Я же рассуждаю, что флексия - это второе название окончания, и запятая перед ИЛИ нужна.
```

Это окончание, или флексия - тоже ИЛИ в знач. "то есть".

"...называется окончанием или флексией" - возможно двоякое понимание - и в знач. "то есть", и в знач. разделительного союза: называют окончанием или называют флексией - по выбору.

Если бы у Вас было:

*Этот инструмент называют флейтой-пикколо или малой флейтой* -

тоже было бы без запятой, здесь значение "называют по выбору - или/или".

Comment: То есть здесь роль играет слово называют. Теперь мне понятно. Значит, я правильно утверждала, что нужна запятая в выражении: Флейта-пикколо, или малая флейта, но отступила от своей точки зрения.Спасибо Вам.